# Detect a touch to the threads

Tags: arduino, sensor, sound

I have a lot of threads stretched vertically. I want to detect the touch them. So that you can then play them like a guitar for example). What is the easiest way to do it (detect touch, not to make a guitar)? What kind of sensors could you recommend for that?

Comment: Provided that these are conductive wires, and not touching each other, then some sort of capacitative sensor will work. Here's an app note from TI on how to do it: http://www.ti.com/mcu/docs/litabsmultiplefilelist.tsp?sectionId=96&tabId=1502&literatureNumber=slaa379&docCategoryId=1&familyId=1937

Comment: By "touch" - you mean "touched by a person", not "touched like a fly touches a spiders web"? Might make a big difference...

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution that would probably work better than capacitive sensing. It's based on extremely high impedance sensing. I'm not sure when they're going to be selling these kits mainstream, but I'm guessing it would fulfill your need.

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/joylabs/makey-makey-an-invention-kit-for-everyone

Comment: Regardless of applicability in this particular case, that's an excellent way to engage kids in STEM from an early age! +1 for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The final choice of solution and success of the implementation will ultimately depend on the mechanical layout of your strings. Proceeding on the idea that the strings are similar to guitar strings, that is, if the strings are sufficiently spaced from one another and the material of the string is still an option, I would use a capacitive touch sensor with conductive strings. You can make adjustments to the sensitivity of the capacitive touch sensor in order to calibrate for activation only when touched.

I've found [this example](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/CapacitiveSensor) for the Arduino using metal wire, which may work for your strings as is.